# when we upload a image in site images.google.co.in,for 2-3 sec the text appears "uploading file" ,am trying to fetch that text,but no success

Tags: file-upload, selenium, selenium-webdriver

when we upload a image in site images.google.co.in,for 2-3 sec the text appears "uploading file" ,am trying to fetch that text,but no success. Below is the code which i have used.

```
             WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get("http://images.google.co.in/");

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //Click on camera type icon in search box 
    driver.findElement(By.id("qbi")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Upload an image")).click();

    //Webelement for browse button
    WebElement UploadImg = driver.findElement(By.name("encoded_image"));

    UploadImg.sendKeys("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Chrysanthemum.jpg");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

     WebElement uploadimage = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='qbupm']")));


     String actualtext=  uploadimage.getText();

     System.out.println(actualtext);
```

Comment: Please add a html sample code

Comment: Hey Anand , its Html is not 4-5 line code ..so can you please have a look at site "http://images.google.co.in/".Also, please let me know if you need more input from my side.